# How do I select the longest string from each vector of strings in a list of vectors?

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors that contain strings, and I am trying to get a list of vectors that only contain the single longest string in each vector.

Example:

What I have:

```
    [[1]]
    [1] "The quick brown fox"
    [2] "jumps over the"
    [3] "lazy dog"

    [[2]]
    [1] "She's a grand old flag"
    [2] "She's a high-flying flag"
    [3] "And forever in peace may she wave"
```

What I want:

```
    [[1]]
    [1] "The quick brown fox"

    [[2]]
    [1] "And forever in peace may she wave"
```

I've tried some combinations of sapply and nchar, but cannot seem to figure it out. I'm thinking I might need to write some sort of loop? 
I'm very new to R, so any advice will be a great help. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly have you tried, so people aren't suggesting something you've already done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
lapply(lst, function(x) x[which.max(nchar(x))])

[[1]]
[1] "The quick brown fox"

[[2]]
[1] "And forever in peace may she wave"
```

Answer (score 0):

Below will handle cases when two strings have same length and are max-length:

`lapply(yourList, function(x) x[nchar(x)==max(nchar(x))])`

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer, if it resolved the problem